# Sinatra-Contrib: undefined method `namespace'

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I'm new to TDD, and I'm trying to write methods to generate URLs on a per-class basis that inherit from a parent class using Sinatra and the Namespace library in Sinatra-Contrib. I'm not too far along, because I've gotten a failed RSpec test that has kept me from moving further: undefined method 'namespace'. Can anyone help?

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sinatra-contrib'
gem 'rack'
gem 'thin'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rack-test'
  gem 'ZenTest'
  gem 'autotest-growl'
  gem 'autotest-fsevent'
end
```

base_model.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/namespace'
require 'rack'

def generate_routes_for_model(model_class, rootUrl)
    namespace rootUrl do
      get '/show' do
        "I'm the model's show route"
      end
    end
end
```

base_model_spec.rb

```
require_relative '../base_model.rb'
require 'rack/test'

set :environment, :test

class Foo
end

def app
    Sinatra::Application
end

include Rack::Test::Methods

describe 'Create Routes for test Class' do
    it "should load foo.show" do
        generate_routes_for_model(Foo, '/foo')
        get '/foo/show'
        last_response.should be_ok
    end
end
```

Here's the result of the test:

Failures:

```
  1) Create Routes for test Class should load foo.show
     Failure/Error: generate_routes_for_model(Foo, '/foo')
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `namespace' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2:0x007f8571102e00>
     # ./base_model.rb:16:in `generate_routes_for_model'
     # ./spec/base_model_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a scope problem, on first look. `namespace` is a [class method of a Sinatra extension](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html#extending-the-dsl-class-context-with-sinatraregister) (which is why you call it within the `class` definition and not inside an instance method).

When you run RSpec, is `namespace` ever within a class that inherits from `Sinatra::Base`? I don't think so. You need to provide a Sinatra class that `namespace` can run within. e.g.

```
class Foo; end

app = Sinatra.new do
  register Sinatra::Namespace
end

def generate_routes_for_model(app_class, model_class, rootUrl)
  ['show'].each do |route|
    app_class.namespace rootUrl do
      get route do
        "I'm the model's show route"
      end
    end
  end
end

generate_routes_for_model app, Foo, "/"
app.run!
```

Then going to `http://localhost:4567/show` will respond with "I'm the model's show route".

Or perhaps use [`class_eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) to define the code, there's a few ways you could tackle this, main thing to keep in mind is make sure the scope is right or the app or RSpec etc won't be able to find the method.

Edit:

Also, I'd move the generation into a `before` block, as it's set up for an integration test (you're essentially saying "If the route exists then the generation worked, I don't need to test the method here", so it's a black box test of the public API - an integration test by any other name:) If you wanted to test the method itself that would be a unit test, and you'd need to look into the `app` to see the routes had been generated.

```
describe 'Create Routes for test Class' do
  before do
    generate_routes_for_model(Foo, '/foo')
    get '/foo/show' # this, too, is not a test but a pre-requisite for the test
  end
  it "should load foo.show" do
    last_response.should be_ok
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @iain, This may be off topic, but can you recommend any resources for learning these TDD techniques?

Comment: @DuncanMalashock no probs. Hmmm, not really :/ There's a dearth of "one stop" resources on this. I've found out stuff in bits and pieces here and there, a lot of it conflicts and is about personal preference. My outlook nowadays is to test outside in - start with integration tests. I save unit testing for helpers, javascript, and complex bits of plumbing. I quite like [BetterSpecs](http://betterspecs.org/), many disagree with the shorter syntax. I've heard good things about https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/, thought I've not used it. Your approach looks fine to me though.